# WDS Deployed Windows 10 image not joining domain

Tags: deployment, wds, windows-10

I'm trying to deploy Windows 10 Pro using WDS running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and everything works fine except for the automatic domain join. It boots to the desktop just fine, but not joined to the domain.

I am able deploy and autojoin Windows 7 and 8.1 with no problems. I've included links to the log files and my answer file below.

Thank you for your help.

[Link to log files and Answer File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7zfaBtbe5fhY1h1ZXNyU1dBd0U)

Comment: Did you ever solve this - I have a similar issue,

Answer (score 1):

In your log there is this :

> 2015-09-03 14:13:09, Error      [0x0b0043] WDS    SelectImage: No
>   images matched the specified criteria.[gle=0x00000002] 2015-09-03
>   14:13:09, Error      [0x0b0049] WDS
>   CallBack_WdsClient_ConnectToImageStore: Error processing unattended
>   image selection. Error [0x80070002][gle=0x00000002]

But since you said it boots fine just not the domain join. Check WDS under properties AD DS , computer account location. If you are trying to put computers in specific OU, and have NOT delegated access rights it will not work. So put them in default domain/computers and then move them off to whatever OU you want.

This seemed to be the case, however it might not work for you.